# When summation of two sequences is finite, is one finite?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

$|\cdot|$ is Lebesgue measure.

Let $w(\alpha) := |\{x:f(x)>\alpha\}|$

Let $f$ be a nonnegative function.

Then, the proof uses that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^{kp}w(2^k)\lt\infty \Longrightarrow w(\alpha)<\infty \text{ in } (0, \infty)$.

Can someone explain why $w(a)$ is clearly finite in $(0, \infty)$?

---

For your information, the proof is about that if $f\ge0$, then $\displaystyle f\in L^p \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^{kp} w(2^k) \lt \infty$

Comment: Of course, the proof uses more than the finiteness of $w(a)$ for every positive $a$, namely, a *quantitative upper bound* of $w(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence of the series implies that $w(2^k)$ is finite for each integer $k$. Now, observe that if $t\gt 0$, then $2^k\leqslant t$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, hence 
$$w(t)\leqslant w(2^ k)<+\infty.$$

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your answer. Can you provide a little bit more detail?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you do not understand?

Comment: Does "The convergence of the series implies that $w(2^k)$ is finite for each integer $k$." mean that "If $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} w(2^k)$ converges to some value, then $w(2^k)$ is finite for each $k$"?? Is it an application of the theorem "if $\sum{}a_k=c$, where $c$ is a constant, then $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = 0$."?

Comment: Actually you do not need to use the fact that the limit is $0$; just notice that all the involved terms in the series have to be finite.

Comment: I got it. Finally, I understood. Thank you very much.